# Stack Overflow when trying to access form controls from class

Tags: c#

I have a problem, after adding this code so I can access my MainWindow controls in Downloader class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    private Downloader fileDownloader;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fileDownloader = new Downloader(this);
    }
//smth
}
```

and

```
class Downloader : MainWindow
{
    private MainWindow _controlsRef;

    public Downloader(MainWindow _controlsRef)
    {
        this._controlsRef = _controlsRef;
    }
// smth
}
```

it now gives me "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll" on line

```
this.mainControlPanel.ResumeLayout(false);
```

in MainWindow.Designer.cs. If i comment out the code above, it works fine. Any ideas please?

PS. Also, when I'm in Downloader class, should i access the controls like

```
textbox.Text
```

or

```
_controlsRef.textbox.Text
```

Both seem to give no compile errors, is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Downloader` class inherits `MainWindow`. When you instansiate it, according to the C# specification, the base class is initialized first. When `MainWindow` initializes, it creates a new instance of `Downloader`, which causes it eventually to stackoverflow, because you're in an endless cyclic dependency.

Since `Downloader` inherits `MainWindow`, there is no point in getting an instance of it via your constructor. You can simply access it's `protected` and `public` members from your derived.

For example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    protected string Bar { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Bar = "bar";
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class Downloader : MainWindow
{
    public void Foo()
    { 
       // Access bar:
       Console.WriteLine(Bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually deleted the inheritance, and refer to controls as _controlRef.control.attribute and it works fine now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's problem because here you are having cyclic dependancy i.e. both the method waiting for each other to complete.

check

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fileDownloader = new Downloader(this);//this wait to complete downloader intialization
    }

  public Downloader(MainWindow _controlsRef)//this wait to complete mainwindow first
    {
        this._controlsRef = _controlsRef;
    }
```

my mean to say as you are inheriting Downloader from MainWindow , which in constructor crating downloader instace...and downloader calls Mainwindow constructor first as its parent crates problem for you here 
Solution

if want reference you can do like this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    protected MainWindow mainWindow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainWindow = this;
    }
//smth
}

class Downloader : MainWindow
{

    public Downloader()
    {
        //this.mainWindow //will give you reference to main winsow
    }
// smth
}
```